# What is the best way to store timezone in Laravel Migrations

Tags: mysql, laravel, timezone, migration

I need to store client's `timezone`.
Haven't found a way to write it to DB using migration (laravel 8.5).
The purpose is like just display current time depends on what timezone user have selected.
What is the best practice to store client's timezone?

Comment: I belive the proper way to go is storing timezone in string and using `Carbon::parse($date)->setTimezone('GMT');`.

Comment: yeah. It might be. So how do i later display the date?
Does $date->timezone($carbon_tz) work in this case?

Comment: If `$date` is a carbon object, yes it should.

Comment: oh yea dude. It works. Can y copy your comment to an answer field and send?
For me to mark yr answer as the right one

Answer (score 0):

Usually the better way is to use UTC timezone in app.config.php , save registered user's timezone in database and display the result accordingly.

Just check this nice blog https://qcode.in/managing-users-timezone-in-laravel-app/